# SPD WF - Change From email address and Set priority flag for Email

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, designer, sharepoint-workflow

We are working on a SharePoint Designer Workflow (SPD WF) in SharePoint Online site and have the following requirement. Can you please let us know if the below requirement can be implementable -

1. Do we have any option to modify the “From” Address of the email in SharePoint Designer Workflow for the SharePoint Online site
2. Do we have option to set the Email as “Non urgent” in SharePoint Designer Workflow for the SharePoint Online site

Answer (score 0):

-Regarding changing of **From** field of email
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/4349bdfd-75c0-46c9-83a7-45471bf85ecc/how-to-change-from-address-of-sharepoint-designer-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

-Regarding setting email priority to high
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136252/sending-an-email-as-high-importance-via-spd-workflow?rq=1

Hope it helps!!